# File outside of allowed directories on brownie compile command

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, chainlink, brownie

trying to import to files from openzeppelin and chainlink in my contract file like so:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

and i have a brownie-config.yaml file that looks like:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2 
  compiler:
    solc:
      remappings: 
        - '@openzeppelin=OpenZepplin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0'
        - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.0.2'
```

when  i run 'brownie compile' command i get:

```
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "https:\github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.4/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "https:\\github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.4/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
^------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

contracts/AdvancedCollectible.sol:6:1: ParserError: Source "https:\github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/release-v1.0.2/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol" not found: File outside of allowed directories.
import "https:\\github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/release-v1.0.2/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
^----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

i also tried importing like below but no luck:

```
import "https:\\github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/release-v3.4/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "https:\\github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/release-v1.0.2/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

Answer (score 3):

So basically i accidentally created the brownie-yaml.config file outside of the project folder.

```
some-folder
 | -project-folder
 |  | -src
 |  | -contracts
 |  | -...
brownie-config.yaml
```

once I move the `.yaml` file into the project folder it all works fine

Comment: Could you please update the answer with what the solution was? This way anyone else will be able to follow along.

Comment: Lovely, that's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had accidentally not left a space after the `-` under the remappings. I had:

```
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      -'@aave=aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1'
...
```

I needed:

```
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      # notice the space
      - '@aave=aave/protocol-v2@1.0.1'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed correctly the yaml file and also did right and left spaces(see above answer)
still got an error to both directories, "not found: File outside of allowed directories."

yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@0.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin = OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.5.0'
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-browniecontracts@0.4.0'
```

importing lines:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCODE. Create a folder .vscode in your root folder and then create a file settings.json inside .vscode with the following content. Ensure the path is correct -

```
{
"solidity.remappings":["@openzeppelin/=/Users/john/workspace/myproject/smart_contract/node_modules/@openzeppelin"] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me i named the file brownie-sonfig.yaml instead of brownie-config.yaml